# QGIS 3.x Python Plugin: Fetch Path to QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer Marker

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am new and currently working on an experimental plug-in for QGIS 3.x. I want to fetch a custom SVG marker used in a MarkerLine (QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer as in https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer.html) within a QGIS 3.x project from the local file system and copy it to a ZIP archive. Locating the marker in a point layer as in QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer is trivial, because QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer supports a path() function (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer.html). I've searched for a similar function in QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer, but couldn't find it.

I seek any hints or code examples.